# Range.FIND - find results in REVERSE ORDER

Tags: excel, vba, windows

O365 Excel (where have they hidden version numbers! Gosh!?)

I have a sheet with 2000+ rows and a column that contains...

```
2 pcs: ...  
3 pcs: ...  
10 pcs: ...  
...
<cursor-position>
```

I wish to FIND the PREVIOUS cell that has "pcs" in it,
so the search should go "backward" (up, toward lesser row number)
ignoring the current cell...

My code has FIND used like this:

```
ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select     ' stay in current column

Selection.Find(What:="Pcs", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _                ' go backwards
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Currently this seems to impossible get going BACKWARDS.

*(The idea here is to achieve a **one time only** re-work of the data,

duplicating the lines, to make there be 10 copies of lines with "10 pcs" stated)

Google searches turns up all but **xlPrevious** thingies.*

---

An additional `After:=ActiveCell, _` doesn't help...

still looking for an answer to this as I'd like to have MY code actually work; and secondarily to get to understand where the problem is.

NOTED: CTRL-F Dialog has no "Search backwards" option.

---

The answers below has shown that there are other (and better) ways to do this, what still remains is to UNDERSTAND why the behavior is as is.
My code is a slightly modified version of a macro *recorded* with "Use Relative references" set.

Comment: I take this to be yet another strange thing in VBA, what you expect is not what you get - looking up things **backward** does not work the same way as looking **forward**. Bugger.

Answer (score 2):

> O365 Excel (where have they hidden version numbers! Gosh!?)

[image]

> Currently this seems to impossible get going BACKWARDS.

For `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` to work, you have to also use the argument `After:=`.

Try this. This code will find the previous match before cell `A100`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set rng = ws.Range("A100")
    
    Set aCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:="Pcs", _
                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   After:=rng, _
                                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then MsgBox aCell.Address
End Sub
```

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set rng = ws.Range("K10")
    
    Set aCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Sid", _
                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   After:=rng, _
                                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then MsgBox aCell.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Without the `After:=rng, _`, this is the result that I get.

[image]

Comment: Ah... one aspect I did not include in my Q, the code is supposed to use relative movements, to allow the cursor move and pinpoint the cell to duplicate. `     After:=ActiveCell, _` - as recorded by excel - did not work. ... Setting a Range() based on Selection might, if I read your code correctly.

Comment: `After:=ActiveCell, _` worked just fine for me

Comment: Oh wait, i know why it did not work with you.. `ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select`. Avoid the use of `.Select`. See how I have done it above, without selecting the column... `ws.Columns(1).Find...`

Comment: You may also want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Right, I need to try that out... tomorrow (this is from a personal project subtask at work). I have very little understanding why the scenario I have shown in the Q would NOT though - in My eyes this is a *blatant* bug. The Q is about a "five minute, quick fix task" that turned out to be all but a nightmare.

Comment: @Hannu the reason your code fails is because when you select the whole column,  the ActiveCell changes to row 1 of the selected column.  When you added `After:=ActiveCell` Find searched after that Cell, ie wrapped to  the bottom of the column and searched up from there.  No bug there, just another example of how Select/Active* can catch you out.  The solution is:you must specify After, and you must accurately specify the cell to search after

Comment: Thank you for trying to pinpoint the actual problem! But visual cue in Excel; the CURSOR remains in the cell where I had it prior to selecting the entire column, and repeated relative movements takes the CURSOR where it is expected from there; but FIND does not.

Comment: *I have yet to have (work-)time to look into this again...*

Comment: @Hannu I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe.  If you want further help, please add a [MRE] to your question (ie a minimal piece of code that reproduces your issue)

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows()

    Dim cel As Range, first As Range, col As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long, t As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        col = ActiveCell.Column
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        
        With .Cells(1, col).Resize(lastrow)
            Set cel = .Find(What:="Pcs", LookIn:=xlValues, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
               MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Set first = cel
                Do
                   n = Val(Split(cel, " ")(0)) ' 10 pcs
                   ' duplicate rows
                   If n > 1 Then
                      cel.EntireRow.Copy
                      cel.Offset(1, 1 - col).Resize(n - 1).Insert xlShiftDown
                      t = t + n - 1
                   End If
                   Set cel = .FindPrevious(cel)
                Loop While cel.Address <> first.Address
            End If
        End With
        
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox t & " rows inserted", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, that is a nice solution to the entire problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Search Previous Using the Find Method

- The code covers the following:

> *I wish to FIND the PREVIOUS cell that has "pcs" in it, so the search
> should go "backward" (up, toward a lesser row number) ignoring the
> current cell...*

- The bigger picture is covered in CDP1802's great code.

**Usage**

- Just select a cell in the column below the relevant data and run the code as many times as necessary. It will just select each matching cell and show a message box with its address.
- When getting tired of it, study the comments in the code.
- Finally, read through the text after the code, and you should have a much larger understanding of the `Find` method.

```vb
Sub TestFind()
    
    ' Check the active cell.
    If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' When? No visible workbooks open or the active sheet is not a worksheet.
    ' Note that the active cell exists even if you have selected a shape,
    ' while 'Selection' in this case is 'Nothing'.
    
    Dim rg As Range, IsInvalid As Boolean
    
    ' Reference the single-column range above the active cell,
    ' e.g. if the active cell is 'J20', then reference the range 'J1:J19'.
    With ActiveCell
        Dim cRow As Long: cRow = .Row
        Dim cCol As Long: cCol = .Column
        If cRow = 1 Then
            IsInvalid = True
        Else
            With .Worksheet
                ' The Find method will fail if the worksheet is filtered!
                If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
                Set rg = .Range(.Cells(1, cCol), .Cells(cRow - 1, cCol))
            End With
        End If
    End With
    
    If IsInvalid Then Exit Sub ' the active cell is in the 1st row
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Attempt to reference the cell closest to the active cell,
    ' i.e. search from the bottom to the top of the range.
    Set cell = rg.Find( _
        What:="pcs", _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    ' I prefer the following...
    'Set cell = rg.Find("pcs", rg.Cells(1), xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlPrevious)
    ' ... but I've done this hundreds of times
    
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No match found.", vbExclamation
    Else
        ' Select the cell.
        cell.Select
        MsgBox "Found a match in cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """.", _
            vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

### The Find Method

- It is one of the most versatile, and therefore complex methods in VBA. Understanding it takes patience and time. There are people using VBA for years and still not understanding it entirely so don't be frustrated.
- It will fail if the worksheet is filtered. It will fail if there are hidden rows or columns and you use the `xlValues` parameter of the `LookIn` argument.
- It has 9 arguments, 7 of which I consider important. In the code, I have used only 4 of these 7. Here is why.

**The Arguments (Important)**

- 1.) `What`. Self-explanatory.
- 2.) `After`. Omitted. This is the most confusing argument. Its default parameter is the first cell of the range. Let's say our range is the range `C2:C10`. Then the default parameter is cell `C2` which means, if the `SearchDirection` argument's parameter is set to `xlPrevious`, the search order will be `C10, C9, ... C2` (which is needed in our case), while if the parameter is set to `xlNext` (or omitted), the search order will be `C3, C4, ... C10, C2`. Note that there is no typo, it's just what it is, the cell supplied to the `After` argument is the last cell searched. So if you want the order to be `C2, C3, ... C10`, you will have to set the cell to cell `C10` usually in the form of `rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count)`. Focus on the word `After` when trying to figure out the logic behind it. Note that this becomes even more complex in a range with multiple rows and columns. Largely depends on the `SearchOrder` and `SearchDirection` arguments.
- 3.) `LookIn`. Its parameter's value is saved each time the `Find` method is called so it is best to always set it explicitly. It is preferable to use `xlFormulas` whenever possible because it will work even if rows or columns are hidden (not filtered). You won't use it if you're looking for partial matches in ranges containing formulas or when you want to ignore non-empty blank cells (e.g. `=""`). Then you'll have to switch to `xlValues` and make sure there are not hidden rows or columns. Additionally, there is an `xlComments` parameter which I've never used. Also, there is an `xlFormulas2` parameter which I know nothing about except that the macro-recorder uses it probably in Microsoft 365 versions of Excel. But those two are irrelevant to our case.
- 4.) `LookAt`. Self-explanatory due to its two possible parameters: `xlWhole` and `xlPart`. Its parameter's value is saved each time the `Find` method is called so it is best to always set it explicitly.
- 5.) `SearchOrder`. Omitted. Irrelevant. Its parameter's value is saved each time the `Find` method is called so it is best to always set it explicitly. You don't have to use it in a single-column or single-row range. You gain nothing by supplying one or the other. Self-explanatory due to its two possible arguments: `xlByRows` and `xlByColumns`. Largely depends on the `SearchDirection` and `After` arguments.
- 6.) `SearchDirection`. Self-explanatory due to its default parameter `xlNext`, and its 2nd possible parameter `xlPrevious`. Largely depends on the `SearchOrder` and `After` arguments.
- 7.) `MatchCase`. Omitted. Its default parameter is `False`, while its 2nd possible parameter is `True`. Rarely you will need a case-sensitive search but when you'll need it, you'll know what to do.

**The Arguments (Not Important)**

- 8.) `MatchByte`. Used with Chinese languages. Saved each time the `Find` method is called. Never used it.
- 9.) `SearchFormat`. Omitted. Its default parameter is `False`, while its 2nd possible parameter is `True`. When you'll need it, google it.